# How to set a value using Rules

Tags: commerce, rules, entities

I want to add an additional field on each orders, and that field can be edited. I've installed the **Field Collections** module. I've added a field in the **order settings** using the **Field Collection** field type. Inside that field, I've created a textarea, **created by** and **edited by** field. I've used entity reference in **created by** and **edited by** to check which user created the field and who edited the field.

How can I set a default value (created by and edited by) when the order has been edited/newly added using rules? or if not possible to do this in rules, is it possible to achieve this in hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's simpler, it really depends on your set up, but you could look at the [Field default token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_default_token):

> This module enables to use tokens as field default values.

with this you can assign default values using tokens, such as current user, etc.